# How to sign up in google play and my country not there?

Tags: android, google-play

I had finished my first app and want to create an account in google play, but i was shocked that the country **Iraq** is missing from the **NAME AND HOME LOCATION** [Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/)

Some people told me that i should find a friend who has Visa card from elsewhere, is it true?

Is it possible to sign up from **Iraq**??

Comment: yes, if your country isnt listed, then you cannot upload payed applications. you can upload free applications though.

Comment: I know it's an old question but did you find a way Yousif? I am in a similar position and would appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @AshrafBawer, you need to get a credit card for another country and then insert billing info (Fake) of that country.

Comment: thanks Yousif. But then is there any way you could withdraw money earned from your apps? Or is it better to just find someone in another country to register an account for you and link his bank account?

Comment: A year ago I met someone who got a MasterCard from the US and he was able to receive money on it and then transfer the money to India then to Iraq via Western Union, but huge some of that money went to the transfer fees. Find a friend to do this for you then try to have a bank account yourself in another country because it is more sustainable than using your friend's account. Wish you best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, If your country is not listed  in google play that means that country is not allowed to upload any kind of applications's on play store.

If you wish to upload you own application on play store then you need to find someone who lives in the country from the list and ask him to follow the procedures and create an account to upload your application and manage it.

Comment: No you can not. Not for free even. Try out once.

Comment: Thanx bro, i'll try and if your are right then i'll accept your answer. **i hate google**

Comment: I found an old friend from another country, if i use his Visa card and give his info in the registration (country, zib code,....), 
is that **OKAY**

Comment: You can not register from your country using your friends details . You need to ask your friend to register from his country for you.

Comment: thanx bro for reply, this's so sad ):

Comment: How much takes for the app to be available to download after uploading it?

Comment: It will take 24 hours.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem before, and I did not find an actual solution that satisfies me, so if you want to upload your applications safely and legally, I advise you to upload them to the Huawei Store as the most suitable solution for you. If this is not what you want, you can try the method that I do not recommend to everyone, which is to ask someone from outside  Iraq, for example, Saudi Arabia - Turkey - Jordan - UAE - Egypt and other supported countries, but be sure to deal with the trusted person so as not to lose the fruit of your efforts.

Comment: He's right. My first google developer account was created for me by a friend who lived in the US at the time. My other accounts were created using fake addresses using a credit card issued from banks located in countries supported by google play.